# How to type String content:encoded = "Hello"; in java?

Tags: java, android, string

How to type `String content:encoded = "Hello";`  in java ? 
Eclipse keep telling me syntax error on tokens delete these tokens ?

```
setDescription(String content:encoded) {
    _description = content:encoded;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are creating method setDescription then it whould be:

```
public void setDescription(String content_encoded) {
    _description = content_encoded;
}
```

Here

1. **public** is `modifier`
2. **void** is `return type`
3. **setDescription** is method name
4. **String** is `parameter type`
5. **content_encoded** is `Variable` that is holding string value.

Comment: boss it could be any thing I am not teaching him/her the coding standard. This is just for his/her understanding.

Answer (score 6):

Because `content:encoded` is a syntax error. Name in java only accept letters numbers `$` and "_". The rule might allow some other characters but it should be pretty much it. Also a variable cannot start with a number.

To be clear, remove the `:` from the variable name because `:` is illegal in a name and might have an other meaning in the language.

Quote from the article below:

> 1. Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and
>      digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign `$`, or the
>      underscore character `_`. The convention, however, is to always begin
>      your variable names with a letter, not `$` or `_`. Additionally, the
>      dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all. You may
>      find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the
>      dollar sign, but your variable names should always avoid using it. A
>      similar convention exists for the underscore character; while it's
>      technically legal to begin your variable's name with `_`, this
>      practice is discouraged. White space is not permitted.
> 2. Subsequent characters may be letters, digits, dollar signs, or underscore characters.

Here read more about it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: Perhaps the first point is enough to address the OP problem. +1.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I removed some of the noise but kept the convetion thing in the first point. I wouldn't want name starting with `$`

Comment: so i can't parse the colon to something like content\u003Aencoded ?

Comment: @A.M.Sid probably not because it's not a letter. Don't misinterpret the text. \u003A is just a codepoint for ":", it doesn't make it a letter. You need a letter, it means you might be able to write code in chinese. You might be able to find in unicode a symbol that will look like \u003A but to be honest, just use the convetion and write with a camel case style `contentEncoded`.